# How to use pandas.read_sql but keep RowVersion formatting?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc

I've been struggling since the morning with this. I have a SQL table with a RowVersion column, that I'm creating using the following code:

```
mycursor = cnxn.cursor()
        
s = """
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  PersonID int PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(255),
  RowVersion rowversion);
  """
        
mycursor.execute(s)
        
sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (PersonID, Name) VALUES (?, ?)"
val = [
       (1, 'Andres'),
       (2, 'Carl'),
       (3, 'Tracy'),
       ]
        
        
mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
cnxn.commit()
```

**Output table:**

| PersonID | Name | RowVersion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Andres | AAAAAAAAD70= |
| 2 | Carl | AAAAAAAAD74= |
| 3 | Tracy | AAAAAAAAD78= |

But once I read the table using `pd.read_sql` or `pd.read_sql_query` the column changes to the following:

```
dfTable = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM table_name", cnxn, coerce_float=False)
dfTable.head()
```

| PersonID | Name | RowVersion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Andres | b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xba' |
| 2 | Carl | b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xbb' |
| 3 | Tracy | b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xbc'' |

What I would like to get is to keep the `RowVersion` format as before. According to the [pd.read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas.read_sql) documentation there is a way to avoid converting non-string values to floating points, but since it is a hex value pandas is reading as a string.

Is there a workaround to find a solution?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reading and altering the table again after uploading the Dataframe as table...

```
s = """
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_name] ADD rv rowversion NULL
"""

mycursor.execute(s)
cnxn.commit()
```

Please, feel free to answer if there is another solution, ty.